# Change the Command Line Interpreter That Visual Studio uses to Launch a Console Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cmd

It possible to change the command line interpreter that visual studio uses to Launch a console application? Currently when launching applications with or without debugging they are run in cmd.exe. I would like to change cmd.exe to a different shell such as Console2 or mintty.

Comment: Can't you simply change the target to debug to your shell then provide your program name as argument?

Comment: I would guess that VS starts the program that is named in the `COMSPEC` environment variable. Try changing that before you start VS.